# Remove JSON object with null value in object node tree

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I have a `JSON` file from which I need to remove node objects which contain a data value of `null`.  Can this be done?  I'm using Jackson.

In the sample `JSON` below, I need to remove the object where its "v" tag has a `null` value.

Example:

```
{
  "tags" : [ {
    "tagId" : "G1.A_90LT1OUT",
    "data" : [ {
      "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:27:36",
      "v" : "96.2427826",
      "q" : "3"
    } ]
  }, {
    "tagId" : "G1.A_90WN1OUT",
    "data" : [ {
      "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:27:36",
      "v" : null,
      "q" : "0"
    } ]
  }, {
    "tagId" : "G1.A_90LT1OUT",
    "data" : [ {
      "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:29:20",
      "v" : "96.2427826",
      "q" : "3"
    } ]
  }, {
    "tagId" : "G1.A_90WN1OUT",
    "data" : [ {
      "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:29:20",
      "v" : null,
      "q" : "0"
    } ]
  }, {
    "tagId" : "G1.A_90LT1OUT",
    "data" : [ {
      "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:29:37",
      "v" : "96.2581177",
      "q" : "3"
    } ]
  }, {
    "tagId" : "G1.A_90WN1OUT",
    "data" : [ {
      "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:29:37",
      "v" : null,
      "q" : "0"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
    {
      "tags" : [ {
        "tagId" : "G1.A_90LT1OUT",
        "data" : [ {
          "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:27:36",
          "v" : "96.2427826",
          "q" : "3"
        } ]
      }, {
        "tagId" : "G1.A_90LT1OUT",
        "data" : [ {
          "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:29:20",
          "v" : "96.2427826",
          "q" : "3"
        } ]
      }, {
        "tagId" : "G1.A_90LT1OUT",
        "data" : [ {
          "ts" : "2019-03-20T15:29:37",
          "v" : "96.2581177",
          "q" : "3"
        } ]
      } ]
    }
```

Can this be done? Please show me how. Fairly new to `JSON` manipulation, I've seen another post that kind of shows how to remove an element from a node, but I think my case is a little different.  I've tried chasing down documentation to no avail, maybe looking in the wrong places.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSONPath

For `JSON` manipulation and filtering you can also use [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library. It has a great [web tool](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) where you can try different filters and options. We can filter all nodes wit not null values using below path:

```
$.tags[?(@.data[0].v != null)]
```

Example application which does the same:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import net.minidev.json.JSONArray;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        JSONArray filtered = JsonPath.parse(jsonFile).read("$.tags[?(@.data[0].v != null)]");

        // Create root object
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
        root.appendField("tags", filtered);

        // Get JSON
        String json = root.toString();

        // Write JSON on console or file
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"tags":[{"tagId":"G1.A_90LT1OUT","data":[{"ts":"2019-03-20T15:27:36","v":"96.2427826","q":"3"}]},{"tagId":"G1.A_90LT1OUT","data":[{"ts":"2019-03-20T15:29:20","v":"96.2427826","q":"3"}]},{"tagId":"G1.A_90LT1OUT","data":[{"ts":"2019-03-20T15:29:37","v":"96.2581177","q":"3"}]}]}
```

### Jackson

The same with `Jackson` we can achieve in that way:

- Read JSON as tree
- Go to `tags` array
- Iterate over array
- For each item find `v` key in `0-index` element
- In case it is `null` - remove it

Example implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        ArrayNode tags = (ArrayNode) root.get("tags");
        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = tags.elements();
        while (elements.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode item = elements.next();
            ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) item.get("data");
            JsonNode v = data.get(0).get("v");
            if (v.isNull()) {
                elements.remove();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you Michal, I knew there where libs there somewhere thanks so much, also the examples are excellent. I like the JsonPath, JsonArray, JsonObject approach, I'm going to try them both.  thank you for such an explicit and thorough explaination.